# How to remove JS error in ruby on rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning ruby on rails and i am trying to add custom JS in my application, but after sometime i removed all the files related to custom JS. But rails still gives me that kind of error, Why?

Can anyone tell me how to remove this because of this my working functionality doesn't work anymore. Thanks in advance.

Here is error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "custom/customJS". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Comment: did you look at your `application.js` file for that line `require('custom/customJS') or import`?
You might also do a global search for that line inside your rails project `require('custom/customJS') or import`

Comment: I did @Moussa but i don't want that folder so i delete this from everywhere but still rails showing me this error. i start server again but no effect